# send a variable from the event observer the magento back end

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, template

i want to send a variable in the magento observer in a custom module to , a template on the admin pages ( phtml , template ) , any help would be welcome .

Comment: Without context, this question does not make much sense. Please explain, **what** you are actually trying to do. Also: What kind of observer? Which template do you want to change and how?

Answer (score 1):

I agree totally with fschmengler.

But to pass something to the frontend you need the Block, like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('BLOCK_NAME___')->setYourVariable('WOHO!');
```

Then you can access it in the template with

```
$this->getYourVariable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento registry for that

for adding data to registory

`Mage::register('my_data', $mydata);`

and getting data from registry where you want to use

`print_r(Mage::registry('my_data'));`

unset data from registry

`Mage::unregister('my_data');`